# Pass function as argument to function

Tags: matlab, function, argument-passing

So I have these two made up .m files. This is an example of the problem I'm having and the math is pseudo-math

rectangle.m:

```
function [vol, surfArea] = rectangle(side1, side2, side3)
vol = ...;
surfArea = ...;
end
```

ratio.m:

```
function r = ratio(f,constant)
% r should return a scaled value of the volume to surface area ratio 
% based on the constant provided.

% This line doesn't work but shows what I'm intending to do.
[vol,surfArea] = f

r = constant*vol*surfArea;
end
```

What I'm unsure how to do is pass the rectangle function as f and then access vol and surfArea from within the ratio function. I've read and the Mathworks page on function handles and function functions and have come up empty handed on figuring out how to do this. I'm new to MATLAB so that doesn't help either.

Let me know if you need anymore info.

Thanks!

Comment: You can pass functions as arguments, for example in `cellfun` but in this example, how do you expect the function to give a result if it doesn't get any arguments?

Comment: So I'm envisioning (incorrectly) the arguments being passed like so. `ratio(rectangle(1,2,3),2)`. However, I'm thinking that this is closer to the correct answer. `ratio(@rectangle,2)` or this `ratio(@(x)ratio(1,2,3),2)`. In both of the last two cases, I don't understand how to access the output from the rectangle function.

Comment: Do you really need to create some sort of functional closure? As the example stands, there's no need for function handles at all - just have the caller call whatever `f` it wants first, then pass the resulting `vol` and `surfArea` as extra arguments to `ratio` (i.e. your `ratio(rectangle(1,2,3),2)` idea)

Comment: your first way to call it would only return the first output of the `rectangle` function. Similarly, anonymous function can only return one output. If you really need to pass function around (whether by their handle or in parameters of other function) and you need multiple values, you  have to group them in a single structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of passing the function `rectangle` as and argument of `ratio` is

```
r = ratio( @recangle, constant )
```

You can then call `[vol,surfArea] = f(s1,s2,s3)` from within `ratio`, but it requires the `sideX` arguments to be known.

If `ratio` should not require to know these arguments, then you could create an object function and pass this as a reference argument. Or better, you could create a rectangle class altogether:

```
classdef Rectangle < handle

    properties
        side1, side2, side3;
    end

    methods

        % Constructor
        function self = Rectangle(s1,s2,s3)
        if nargin == 3
            self.set_sides(s1,s2,s3);
        end
        end

        % Set sides in one call
        function set_sides(self,s1,s2,s3)
            self.side1 = s1;
            self.side2 = s2;
            self.side3 = s3;
        end

        function v = volume(self)
            % compute volume
        end

        function s = surface_area(self)
            % compute surface area
        end

        function r = ratio(self)
            r = self.volume() / self.surface_area();
        end

        function r = scaled_ratio(self,constant)
            r = constant * self.ratio();
        end

    end

end
```

Comment: So this is correct. However, one thing I didn't mention (and didn't expect anyone to get) was some arguments of rectangle I wanted to inherit into the ratio function, and other's I wanted to manipulate from within the ratio function. I'll write up what I figured out today but for all intents and purposes, your solution would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

While I didn't bring this up in my question above, this is what I was searching for.

So what I wanted to do was pass some of rectangles arguments to ratio while being able to manipulate any chosen number of rectangles arguments from within the ratio function. Given my .m files that above, a third .m would look something like this. This solution ended up using [MATLAB's anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

**CalcRatio.m:**

```
function cr = calcRatio(length)
% Calculates different volume to surface area ratios given
% given different lengths of side2 of the rectangle.
cr = ratio(@(x) rectangle(4,x,7); %<-- allows the 2nd argument to be 
                                  % manipulated by ratio function
end
```

**ratio.m:**

```
function r = ratio(f,constant)
% r should return a scaled value of the volume to surface area ratio 
% based on the constant provided.

% Uses constant as length for side2 - 
% again, math doesnt make any sense, just showing what I wanted to do.
[vol,surfArea] = f(constant);

r = constant*vol*surfArea;
end
```